# How to Draw Circle, incrementally, to create an animated fill effect (using Corona)

Tags: lua, geometry, coronasdk, geometry-surface

I'm having trouble even figuring out where to start with this. ANY help would be highly appreciated!

Using the Corona SDK I want to draw a circle that will slowly fill as a percentage increases.

The fill effect will follow the path of the circle, going anti-clockwise until the entire circle/area is completely filled a different color.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you even have anything you've tried? Have you actually gotten the circle itself drawing/working? We need to know what all you've tried and what's not working. Cases like these often are looked unfavorably upon because no one wants to do all the work for you.

Comment: "I am having trouble figuring out where to start with this." seems like a pretty legitimate precursor to not having a prototype to draw upon for his question. This is one of those cases where it's better to just let the question linger until someone who actually understands the Corona SDK can chime in and provide some assistance, and perhaps edit this question until it becomes a valuable Lua+Corona community asset for anyone else looking to do the same thing. (Which, oddly, I was when I landed here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sample from caronalabs.com forums](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/26655-display-ellipse-with-an-angle/) shows how you might draw an arc, which provides the discrete algorithm you would need to do what you're asking:

```
function display.newArc(group, x,y,w,h,s,e,rot) 
    local theArc = display.newGroup()

    local xc,yc,xt,yt,cos,sin = 0,0,0,0,math.cos,math.sin --w/2,h/2,0,0,math.cos,math.sin
    s,e = s or 0, e or 360
    s,e = math.rad(s),math.rad(e)
    w,h = w/2,h/2
    local l = display.newLine(0,0,0,0)
    l:setColor(54, 251, 9)
    l.width = 4

    theArc:insert( l )

    for t=s,e,0.02 do 
        local cx,cy = xc + w*cos(t), yc - h*sin(t)
        l:append(cx,cy) 
    end

    group:insert( theArc )

    -- Center, Rotate, then translate       
    theArc.x,theArc.y = 0,0
    theArc.rotation = rot
    theArc.x,theArc.y = x,y

    return theArc
end

function display.newEllipse(group, x, y, w, h, rot)
    return newArc(group, x, y, w, h, nil, nil, rot)
end
```

It would appear that all you need to do is continue allocating new lines from the center out to the circumference of the circle over time.

Disclaimer: I've not tested this code, you will likely need to modify it further, but at a glance the math looks correct.

HTH!

Comment: Sorry I didn't thank you earlier. This worked perfectly for what I wanted, thanks!